# Tab Bar Color Slightly Changing with View BackgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, uitabbar

Is there anyway to keep the tab bar color exactly the same regardless of the color of the view in the view controllers? The bottom picture with dashboard selected is darker than the top one because the view.backGroundcolor = .lightGray in the view controller.

[image]

I tried setting the view.bottomAnchor equal to the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, but even then if the view is set as light gray, the tab bar will be slightly darker than the view controllers that have a white background.
I also set the self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
and self.tabBar.alpha = 1.0

It's not just a perception thing either as I checked the exact color in hexcode.

Relevant lines of code :

```
final class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
        self.tabBar.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Should this code go in the init instead that sets up the corresponding view controllers?

Comment: Can you give an image for you problem? It's easier to understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Added it into the post

Comment: I see nothing "wrong" with the image you've posted. How does it illustrate a _problem_?

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se, but it does change color slightly depending on the color of the background in the view controller and I would like it to stay the same for each tab

Comment: I used the color eyedropper tool on both tab bars in your screen shot and they are both the same color — white. I think you're suffering some kind of optical illusion.

Comment: @user3628240 Do you mean that each time you select a tab, tabBarController will change color base on background color of view controller?

Comment: @matt Maybe the setting isTranslucent to false did the trick, but I was using eyedropper before and they were coming out as separate colors. Thanks for the help

Comment: @trungduc Yes the base seemed to change color depending on the background color of the view controller. I think setting it to isTranslucent may have worked

Answer (score 1):

The color you are setting for the tab bar is only a *tint*. The only way to get *absolute* control over the color is to make a resizable UIImage of the desired color and set the tab bar's `backgroundImage` property.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623469-backgroundimage